# Wamp PHP very slow on windows 10

Tags: php, performance, apache, wamp

When I try to load simple html page everything works fast. Yet when i write a simple php connect command to connect to mysql database, takes about 15-25 seconds to retrieve an answer if the connection was successful or not. I am not even talking about the time it takes to retrieve more difficult data :)
I have already tried all the solutions in:

https://ineed.coffee/1441/apache-php-mysql-slow-under-windows-8-how-to-fix/

Yet it didn't help. No improvement in loading speed at all. 
I noticed that my httpd.conf file has these lines:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Yet I don't know if it has any influence or not, just guessing :D
As you probably understood I am new with this wamp thing, and have not a slightest idea how can I fix it. So my only chance are you guys :)

Comment: Is there the same issue with a simple php file doing a simple write but without the mysql part ? (to help identify if the issue is linked to mysql or to php)

Comment: if I remove the connect to mysql part only leave simple php code, the problem is gone

Comment: Can you share your php code that connects to mysql ? (obfuscate the password obviously :) )

Answer (score 0):

comment the line of ipv6 on the hosts file. It is in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

You should edit like administrator.
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1           localhost
```

Grettings!

Comment: Did this solve the issue for anyone? It didn't work for me.